# DSC (Desired State Configuration)

Tags: powershell, dsc

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between running DSC script by Powershell ISE vs standard console (both run as administrator)?

When I run my script by PS ISE everything works fine, DSC applies to 2 servers incl. encryption. But when I run exactly the same script by 'Run with Powershell' I'm getting such error messages:

> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.    at
> System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
> funcContext, Exception exception)    at
> System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
> frame)    at
> System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
> frame)    at
> System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
> frame).
>
> line 1021 at ScriptBlock, No file: line 1

These errors point to the below line (in bold):

```
Configuration Config1
{
...
...
...
}
$configdata = @{
        AllNodes = @(
            @{
                NodeName = "Server1"
                PSDscAllowDomainUser = $true
                CertificateFile = "$((Get-ChildItem 'E:\' | ? {$_.Name -like 'MyFolderName'}).fullname)\Server1.cer"
                Thumbprint = ($Thumbs | ? {$_ -like "Server1*"}).Split("=")[1]
            }
            @{
                NodeName = "Server2"
                PSDscAllowDomainUser = $true
                CertificateFile = "$((Get-ChildItem 'E:\' | ? {$_.Name -like MyFolderName'}).fullname)\Server2.cer"
                Thumbprint = ($Thumbs | ? {$_ -like "Server2*"}).Split("=")[1]
             }
        )
    }

Config1 -ConfigurationData $configdata
```

The problem is with the Server2 (I'm running script on Server1). All paths are correct, can I use such syntax in the hashtable?

The problem is with the standard powershell console, does anybody know why PS ISE does not return any errors?

Comment: If you are seeing a different between code run in standard powershell console vs the powershell ISE I would check your powershell profiles. There is a different profile powershell will run in  ISE vs the standard console. [About Profiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/ise/how-to-use-profiles-in-windows-powershell-ise)

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much everything you would do with DSC, with straight powershell code. The code describing your system in the configuration management system will be checked and ran against your system periodically.

DSC and many other configuration management systems is about making re-usable resources that actually do the work that can be shared.

This is one of the reasons why the general script is not able to pick the configurations.
In your case, you got one Runtime Exception which clearly depicts that some value which had been passed to a method in the script was NULL.

Go through the Following Links:

[Powershell DSC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/privatecloud/2013/08/30/introducing-powershell-desired-state-configuration-dsc/)

[Configuration Management Theory - Idempotence & Immutability](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/WinOps/WinOps-Conf-2016/Configuration-Management-Theory-Why-idempotence-and-immutability)

[Configuration Management](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-configuration-management)

Comment: Thank you for reply but I'm still don't know how to accomplish such scenario:
1. Run script with all required information that will execute Start-DSCConfiguration on Server1 (encrypted MOF files for Server1 and Server2)
2.  From Server1 execute Test-DSCConfiguration for both servers with success
I tried to go follow this article (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/securemof?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but without success...